# Increment all defines/enums in a source file

Tags: sed, enums, text-editor

Say I have a many (100+) defines/enumerations/variables such as:

```
FOO:    1
BAR:    2
QUX:    3
// ...
ZYX:   99
XYZ:  100
```

I want to add a new line: `BAZ:   3` after `BAR`, and update `QUX`'s  value to '4', as well as updating the rest of the values. What's the most efficient, easiest solution to increment all of the values after `BAZ`, using built-in/native unix text editing tools (like text editors, sed, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this input file:

```
$ cat file
FOO:    1
BAR:    2
QUX:    3
// ...
ZYX:   99
XYZ:  100
```

This inserts BAZ after BAR and increments every number after that:

```
$ awk 'NR==1,/^BAR:/{print;next} !f{print "BAZ: 3";f=1} /^[[:alnum:]]+:/{print $1,++$2;next} 1' file
FOO:    1
BAR:    2
BAZ: 3
QUX: 4
// ...
ZYX: 100
XYZ: 101
```

#### How it works

- `NR==1,/^BAR:/{print;next}`

  Print all lines up to and including the first line beginning with `BAR:`, then jump to next line
- `!f{print "BAZ: 3";f=1}`

  We only get to this line after `BAR` has been encountered.  Here, add the `BAZ` line and set flag `f` to one so that we know not to add it again.
- `/^[[:alnum:]]+:/{print $1,++$2;next}`

  For any line line starting with an identifier followed by a colon, increment the number after the colon and skip to the next line.
- `1`

  For all other lines, such as `//...`, print them as is.  (`1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for printing the line as is.)

Answer (score 1):

awk seems easiest:

```
awk '{ $2 += n; print } $1 == "BAR:" { n = 1; print "BAZ:", $2 + 1 }' filename
```

This is to be read as follows:

```
{                       # for all lines:
  $2 += n               # increase second field by remembered number
                        # (initially 0)
  print                 # print line with that change
}
$1 == "BAR:" {          # When the first field in the line was "BAR:"
  n = 1                 # set offset
  print "BAZ:", $2 + 1  # insert new line
}
```

I assume that there is only one `BAR:` line in the whole file; in the event that this is not guaranteed, you may want to amend this to

```
awk '{ $2 += n; print } !n && $1 == "BAR:" { n = 1; print "BAZ:", $2 + 1 }' filename
```

to have a `BAZ:` line inserted only after the first `BAR:`, or

```
awk '{ $2 += n; print } $1 == "BAR:" { ++n; print "BAZ:", $2 + n }' filename
```

to have a `BAZ:` line inserted after each appearance of `BAR:` while keeping the numbering intact. Both of these variants work with the simple input, of course.

For pretty formatting, you can use the `sprintf` builtin:

```
awk '{ $2 = sprintf("%4d", $2 + n); print } $1 == "BAR:" { ++n; print "BAZ:", sprintf("%4d", $2 + n) }' filename
```

This will lead to the following output:

```
FOO:    1
BAR:    2
BAZ:    3
QUX:    4
...
ZYX:  100
XYZ:  101
```